# Что делать с пользователем у которого все ответы - это скопированные комментарии?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Под одним из вопросов заметил пользователя, зашел в профиль и как оказалось абсолютно его все сообщения - копирование комментариев под тем  же самым вопросом.

Вопрос - как поспособствовать принятию мер и как минимум модерации всех его "ответов"?

(Профиль - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/401315/bog)

Comment: Недавно попался [**такой участник**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/398755/jokerbot) → я поставил тревоги на его ответы → модератор Suvitruf добавил к ответам фразы вида «Как посоветовал участник N в комментариях», [**пример**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1154748/revisions). Спасибо.